# Convert 2019 Giant TCX Advanced Pro 2 1x to 2x

Tags: drivetrain

I'm looking at a 2019 Giant TCX Advanced Pro 2 which was sold as a 1x.  I have a Shimano 2x groupset laying around and would love this bike as a 2x.

Based on this image from [this sold listing](https://www.theproscloset.com/products/giant-tcx-advanced-pro-2-cyclocross-bike-2019-small), it looks like there's a spare entry into the downtube:

[image: Photograph of Giant TCX Advanced Pro 2 Cyclocross Bike - 2019, Small]

And this review shows a hole behind the seat tube above the BB:

[image: Photograph of Giant TCX Advanced Pro 2]

Are my eyes decieving me or could I run gear cable down that and into a front derailleur?

Comment: There does seem to be a rubber plug on the right hand side of the seat tube - it may cover some tapped holes for a braze-on mount.  You might try contacting Giant, or find a user/service manual for this frame.

Comment: Is there any penetration or hole on the bottom of the bottom bracket area where you could feed a cable through?  That would align with the standard cable guide bolted to the bottom bracket of bikes that have a front derailleur?  Is the seat tube perfectly round in the area where a derailleur mounting band would go?  Is the seat tube the right size in that area so a derailleur mount would fit properly?  If not, and this would be all-internal routing, how would you feed a shift cable through the frame?

Comment: There is also an unused exit hole closer to the head tube. Seems like this frame is not 1×-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response finally came through from Giant:

> Yes, you should be able to route cable for a front derailleur.

Comment: Great find - thank you for coming back with a verified answer from an authorative source.